# crontab dont execute require

Tags: ruby, macos, cron

I'm using a osx and I created a ruby script in the path: `/Users/diogo/workspace/outros/crawler_trf` with name `get_news.rb`

So I tried to execute it via crontab with the following line: `*/1 * * * * 'ruby /Users/diogo/workspace/outros/crawler_trf/get_news.rb' > /tmp/crawler_trf.out` and I've got the error: `/bin/sh: ruby /Users/diogo/workspace/outros/crawler_trf/get_news.rb: No such file or directory`

After some searches and a question here I solved this problem removing the quotes and now my crontab looks like that: `*/1 * * * * cd /Users/diogo/workspace/outros/crawler_trf/ && ruby get_news.rb > /tmp/crawler_trf.out`

But now I'm having a new error that is:

```
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require': cannot load such file -- mail (LoadError)
from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
from get_news.rb:3:in `<main>'
```

The beginning of my file is:

```
require 'nokogiri'
require 'open-uri'
require 'mail'
```

My ruby version is 2.3.0 and I have it specified in `.ruby-version` and using gemset specified in `.ruby-gemset

I installed the gems via bundle

I really had searching for my answers for long but I didn't found nothing.

Comment: how are you installing these gems? Have you run `gem install` for them all? Or, if they're in the project's Gemfile, try `bundle exec ruby` instead.

Comment: if I execute with bundle receive error `/bin/sh: bundle: command not found`
I'll edit my post adding my ruby version and how I install the gems

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should always fully specify the paths of all files when executing them out of cron, since the environment provided by cron will be different from your login environment. That might mean replacing the invocation of `ruby` with the full path to your ruby binary (maybe `/usr/local/bin/ruby`).

Try running `ruby -v` out of cron to see what version you are picking up. On my Mac OS system I have two:

```
Edwards-MacBook-Air:~ emv$ /usr/bin/ruby -v
ruby 2.0.0p648 (2015-12-16 revision 53162) [universal.x86_64-darwin15]
Edwards-MacBook-Air:~ emv$ /usr/local/bin/ruby -v
ruby 2.3.1p112 (2016-04-26 revision 54768) [x86_64-darwin15]
```

one from the operating system, and one from Homebrew.

Comment: I dont find `/usr/local/bin/ruby` and the response of `ruby -v` was

    ruby 2.3.0p0 (2015-12-25 revision 53290) [x86_64-darwin14]

Comment: I looked for ruby binaries with `which ruby` and found it in `/Users/diogo/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/bin/ruby` I changed the crontab to execute with this path and the error is the same ;(

Comment: Ah, you are using `rvm`. Did you look at https://rvm.io/integration/cron (Using rvm wtih cron). It references calling a wrapper like so `1 0  * * * /usr/local/rvm/wrappers/ruby-2.1.1@projectX/ruby /path/to/script.rb`